# Why is Catel's TabControl not getting themed by MahApps?

Tags: xaml, mahapps.metro, catel, orchestra

Pretty much title. catel:TabControl's background remains white whatever MahApps' theme is.

I can't tell if it's the only Catel control behaving this way, since I didn't test every and each one of them.

But there it is, it's not getting affected by MahApps' selected theme (BaseDark or BaseLight). It wasn't obvious since I started with the light one, so the TabControl was white as expected, but once I switch to the dark theme, it remains white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is already solved in Orchestra (https://github.com/WildGums/Orchestra).

I think you should override the Catel's tab control style like following:

    `<windows:MetroDataWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="catel:TabControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabControl}}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </windows:MetroDataWindow.Resources>`

You can check the example in the Orchestra.Shell.MahApps project in Orchestra:

Points of interest:

- Orchestra.Examples.MahApps/Orchestra.Examples.MahApps.Shared/Views/MainView.xaml
- Orchestra.Shell/Orchestra.Shell.MahApps/Orchestra.Shell.MahApps.Shared/Views/ShellWindow.xaml

To enable dark MahApps theme in Orchestra you should add the following code to Orchestra.Shell/Orchestra.Shell.MahApps/Orchestra.Shell.MahApps.Shared/Themes/Generic.xaml

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />`

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I guess catel:TabControl doesn't inherit TabControl.